# Find eloquent model and related model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I need to find a user's goal by id.

A user has many goals.

I'm not sure how to do this, I imagine the snippet could look something like this.

```
$goal = User::find($userId)->goals()->find($id);
```

Is it possible to fetch a related model and filter on a parent model at the same time?

Comment: When you already have the $id for goal - assuming that $id corresponds to the primary key of goals table, why do you need to go through the User model. You can directly get the goal record using the primary key `$goal = Goal::findOrFail($id);`

Comment: I want to make sure the goal belongs to the user

Comment: Policies should be used for authorization, instead of tacking bits onto queries! https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#creating-policies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict the related records by using a constraint while eager loading the relationship and then get the first one

```php
$goal = User::with(['goals' => fn($query) => $query->where('goals.id', $id)])
    ->findOrFail($userId)
    ->goals
    ->first();

//Then check whether a goal is present as per the constraint before proceeding further

if($goal) {
    //Do something
}
```

Another option would be to go through the `goals` table

```php
$goal = Goal::with('users')->findOrFail($id);

if($goal->users->contains('id', $userId) {
    echo "User with an id of {$userId} has the given goal";

    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!